# install luajit error: no member named 'J' in 'GG_State'

Tags: 64-bit, luajit

I want to install LuaJIT-2.1.0-beta2 in my MacbookAir, when I run the commond "make", it throw some error info like this.

```
==== Building LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2 ====

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C src
HOSTCC    host/buildvm.o
In file included from host/buildvm.c:73:
vm_x86.dasc:2642:109: error: no member named 'J' in 'GG_State'
  ...Dt7(->pc), PC2PROTO(framesize), Dt1(->base), Dt1(->top), GG_DISP2J, DISP...

./lj_dispatch.h:112:20: note: expanded from macro 'GG_DISP2J'
#define GG_DISP2J       (GG_OFS(J) - GG_OFS(dispatch))

./lj_dispatch.h:103:29: note: expanded from macro 'GG_OFS'
#define GG_OFS(field)   ((int)offsetof(GG_State, field))

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: 
      expanded from macro 'offsetof'
define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)


......

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: 
      expanded from macro 'offsetof'
 define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)

14 errors generated.
make[1]: [host/buildvm.o] Error 1
make:  [default] Error 2
```

I dont know what's wrong with it, will U help me? Thank U very much.(This is my first question here, and my English is poor.Anything need to modify Please tell me, sorry and Thanks.)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use 2.1.0-beta2? There's a more recent version, 2.1.0-beta3, that includes several bug fixes. I'd give a try to 2.1.0-beta3 or even better build the current v2.1 tip of master.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Year，I have a very old project that needs maintenance(with quick-cocos2dx-2.2.1& Luajit2.1.0-beta2). I have tried 2.1.0-beta3 too, it shows the similar errors.